# Animated move of UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, ipad

So, I have a setup where an UIPopoverController presents information at the cursor in a text view. When the cursor moves, I present it again. But this is jarring, and I'd like for the popover to move in a smooth, animated fashion. Will I really have to do that manually by using a series of presentFromRect calls, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `UIPopover`s are not designed to be moved around like that.

The only way to do that without presenting it all over again is to write your own `UIPopover` replacement and animate its position using the standard `CAAnimation` or `UIKit` animation techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If think you cannot do that without use `presentFromRect`. But if you really want to do this, create your own. Recreate the look of a popover controller using a UIView and track the touches. You can use an alternative like [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover).